# How to implement a stopping condition for splitting an image matrix into pixels?

Tags: python

I'm currently using Python to split a binary list into quadrants. For example:

```
11110000        1111 0000          11 11 00 00     
11110000        1111 0000          11 11 00 00
00011100        0001 1100                       
00011100   ==>  0001 1100          00 01 11 00
11110000                           00 01 11 00 
11110000        1111 0000   ==>                       
11110011        1111 0000          11 11 00 00 
11110011        1111 0011          11 11 00 00
                1111 0011                            
                                   11 11 00 11
                                   11 11 00 11
```

My program receives an input `n` which signifies the size of the `n x n` matrix. In the example above, `n = 8`.

The function that I've written to do that is:

```
def divide_to_quadrants(original):
    quad_size = len(original) // 2

    q1 = [i[:quad_size] for i in original][:quad_size]
    q2 = [i[quad_size:] for i in original][:quad_size]
    q3 = [i[:quad_size] for i in original][quad_size:]
    q4 = [i[quad_size:] for i in original][quad_size:]

    return [q1, q2, q3, q4]
```

I want to ultimately end up with quadrants that are only a single unit, but I'm having trouble coming up with a way to implement that with varying values of `n`.

I thought of indexing one of the quadrants and checking to see if the length is 1, but since each image size will have varying number of times until they reach single-unit quadrants, that doesn't seem like a viable solution either.

Is there any way that I would be able to do this? Thanks.

#### Edit

`n` is an exponent of 2, and the quadrants should be split into equal sizes. That means that an image of `8 x 8` would be split into four quadrants of `4 x 4`, and an image of size `32 x 32` would be split into four `16 x 16` and so on.

The image is a Python list which contains strings, so it looks like `['11110000', '11110000', '00011100' ...]`. I believe that it wouldn't be a problem if these strings were separate integers though.

Comment: Does the number of "groups" need to evenly divide `n`?  Would you want to split a 9x9 into a 3x3 of 3x3's?  Or would you prefer splitting it into unequal quadrants?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll edit the question to reflect the missing information. Thanks!

Comment: Can you convert this to numpy?  This would be relatively easy with numpy indexing.

Comment: @Sean Your function seams to work well. Maybe it would be nice to add `quad_size > 0` Do you expect to use the result of a function as an argument for itself? What's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

It may actually be easier to do this iteratively than recursively:

```py
def pair(values):
    iterator = iter(values)
    return [(x, next(iterator)) for x in iterator]

def format_block(lines):
    formatted_lines  = [" ".join("".join(unit) for unit in pair(line)) for line in lines]
    formatted_output = "\n\n".join("\n".join(line_pair) for line_pair in pair(formatted_lines))
    return formatted_output
```

Result

```py
>>> lines = ["11111111"] * 8
>>> print(format_block(lines))
11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11

11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11

11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11

11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11
```

Comment: It's a neat trick, but it's not an answer. You're pushing things to _look_ like an answer. IMO until the OP clarifies the nature and purpose of the output, it will be hard to do anything meaningful with it. Note that @Sean didn't specify whether this is a recursive task or a one-time splitting with some boundary problem.

Comment: p.s. BTW don't you think that splitting an image matrix into pixels is sort of a dummy problem?

Comment: @Vitalizzare it should be obvious how to adapt the above code to return the pairs themselves, as opposed to a formatted string. If that's what OP wants afterall. 
If they require recursively nesting the lists, on top of that, then I blame the post for being too ambiguous.